# How to get current route with its options in angular2 directives

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I'm searching for a way that access to route that have been loaded.

in initially the route changes can be subscribe by router events like follow :

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myDirective]' })
export class TestDirective {

    constructor(private _router: Router) {
        this.doAction()
    }


    doAction(): void {
        this._router.events
            .filter((event: Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .subscribe(event => {
                /// ... get current route data
            })
        }

    }
}
```

the main question is that how to get current route data in subscribe() ???

in angular 2 documents and with searching no result founded.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for your issue, please try this.

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

currentRoute:any;

constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((url) => {
      this.currentRoute = url;
      console.log(this.currentRoute);
    });
  }
```

You will get a console like bellow
[image]

**GETTING VALUES FROM Query parms**

```
import { Router, Route, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

queryParams:string;

constructor(private router: Router, private actRoute: ActivatedRoute) 
{
    this.queryParams=
    this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.queryParams["oauth_token"];
}
```

Using this you will get the value of oauth_token to queryParams. I think this seems fine for you

NB: your url will be like  http://example.com?oauth_token=123

Comment: I want take (route.data) value !! your way can do by Router.config() and get a search in the returned object for easy path like "/login" but it's hard to parse a url with optional params like "/heroes/:id" or "/posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id"

Comment: You need to get the query parameter rite ?  
K i will update the answer

Comment: no !!! for example I want to pass a data in route config named "hasHeader": (true|false), then in directive in each rout change I need to get this data from loaded route !!! query params not be good !!